# Calculate Two Quadrilateral Intersection Area

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, area

Please I need some help calculating the area of intersection between two quadrilaterals

my work till now:

quadrilateral 1 (A):
points -> [(x0,y0),(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)]

quadrilateral 2 (B):
points -> [(i0,j0),(i1,j1),(i2,j2),(i3,j3)]

```
y = (slope * x) + constant
```

at the intersection point

```
(slope1 * x) + constant1 = (slope2 * i) + constant2
```

at this point x = i but we do not know its value so:

```
x = (constant2 - constant1) / (slope1 - slope2)
```

using this equation I'm able to get all intersection points event if it's not into any of quadrilateral

I stopped at this point, so I need some help to continue and calculate the intersection area using mathematical equations without any if else blocks.

Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, it is an almost impossible task : there are too many intricated (therefore almost intractable) cases. Even the particular case of the common area of two triangles (by which you should begin) is very complicated... and you need many "if" conditions...

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! <> To supplement Jean Marie's comment, is an _algorithm_ enough? That looks a lot easier than a _formula_. For two triangles, use the sides of one triangle to clip the other, then (if the intersection is non-empty) calculate the area of the resulting polygon by vector algebra. Then split your quadrilaterals into two triangles and sum the resulting areas from the four overlaps of triangles.